# Equivalent of quadraticCurveTo in PHP

Tags: php, draw, curve

i'm searching for an equivalent of the javascript function quadraticCurveTo in php.

```
ctx.moveTo(this.fromX,this.fromY);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.controlX, this.controlY, this.toX, this.toY);
```

My script gets the variables (fromx,fromy,controlx...) from POST and i want to draw the curve with GD or anything else.

Edit: Resolved! See my comment

Comment: i found how to do it.
I used Imagemagick here is the code.

`$draw->pathStart();`
`$draw->pathLineToAbsolute($arrow[0], $arrow[1]);`
`$draw->pathCurveToQuadraticBezierAbsolute($arrow[2], $arrow[3],$arrow[4], $arrow[5]);`
`$draw->PathFinish();`

Comment: You should add the above as an answer an accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found how to do it. I used Imagemagick here is the code.

```
$draw->pathStart();
$draw->pathLineToAbsolute($arrow[0], $arrow[1]);
$draw->pathCurveToQuadraticBezierAbsolute($arrow[2], $arrow[3],$arrow[4], $arrow[5]);
$draw->PathFinish();
```